# PHP form not POSTing multiple select fields

Tags: php, html, post

My PHP form is not POSTing any of the multiple select options I have in a form.
This is my PHP:

```
if ($_POST['interested_in_testing'] != "")
{
    $_POST['interested_in_testing'] = filter_var($_POST['interested_in_testing'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    $interested_in_testing = $_POST['interested_in_testing'];
}
else
    died();
```

Add to email:

```
<br/>Interested In Testing: " . $interested_in_testing ;
```

This is my select:

```
<label class="custom">Interested In Testing</label>
<select name="interested_in_testing[ ]" multiple="multiple">
  <option value="atas">ATAs</option>
  <option value="ip_phones">IP Phones</option>
  <option value="gateways">Gateways</option>
  <option value="ip_pbx">IP PBX</option>
</select>
```

It doesn't send anything for this field. All my single fields send fine. Any help? Thank you

Comment: Its an array so treat it like one `name="interested_in_testing[]"` so `!empty($_POST['interested_in_testing'][0])`.. ..

Comment: Add a print_r($_POST); in your code (before the if) and tell us what is displayed please

Comment: also <select name="interested_in_testing[ ]" multiple="multiple"> should be <select name="interested_in_testing[]" multiple="multiple"> no space in []

Comment: I originally had it without the space. I was trying things :/ @Raphael Malie Since it is an email it doesn't recognize the non html

Comment: it's a select. why no use checkboxes if you want multiple values?

Comment: @FélixGagnon-Grenier That is a good suggestion. I likely will do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are creating an array element, you should consider the same as an array on other end as well.

```
if (is_array($_POST['interested_in_testing']) && !empty($_POST['interested_in_testing'])) {
    $interested_in_testing_val = array();
    foreach($_POST['interested_in_testing'] as $val) {
        $interested_in_testing_val[] = $val;
    }
    $interested_in_testing = implode(',', $interested_in_testing_val);
}
```

*Assumming you want the values as comma separated.*

Comment: Spaces are allowed within the brackets of a select's name attribute.

Comment: I am new to PHP, treating it as an Array was correct in my if statement.